# addind FILE_SHARE_READ mode with cygwin

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin

I did a very simple program in C for linux a few months ago to read data from a socket and write it to disk. Now I want to run it on Windows, so I installed cygwin and everything worked fine.

The problem appears in windows when my program is writing the data to a file and, at the same time, I try to open that file with another tool. It complains and doesn't open the file because it is opened by other process.

After googleing, I have read that to avoid that, in windows, you have to create the file with SHARE_FILE_READ and SHARE_FILE_WRITE flags, but the problem is that my program is written in C for linux and I just use a standard open syscall..

Is there any way to tell cygwin to add that shared modes to the file that my program is opening?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that *both* processes which open the file must do so with compatible sharing modes in order to succeed.  Cygwin is opening the file with the correct sharing mode, but the other program is not.

For all files which are not special device files for tape drives, Cygwin opens them by calling `NtCreateFile` with a sharing mode of `FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS` (equivalent to `FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE`)—see the implementation of  `fhandler_base::open()` in [`fhandler.cc`](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/winsup/cygwin/fhandler.cc?rev=1.433&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=src), which is what `fopen()`, `open()` etc. all use under the hood.

You need to convince your other program to open the file with the correct sharing mode; if it uses a sharing mode of 0 (no sharing), then it doesn't matter how Cygwin opens the file—the program will always get a sharing violation in that case.